# Angular Preflight Request to Add Headers

Tags: angular, security, web, preflight

I have this project running in Angular 8 and does call api's with preflight and the actual API. And we have a problem on it's web security due to the preflight OPTIONS doesnt have the header **Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains** while the actual GET api has one.

Do you have any idea if how and where to  add the **Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains** under preflight and the actual request so that two requests will have the same headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is the way for to set HttpHeader into a request.**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class HttpClient {

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  get(url) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Transport-Security', 'max-age=31536000;includeSubDomains')

    return this.http.get(url, {
      headers: headers
    });
  }


}
```

Comment: i tried adding it in the header in httpclient, but i got CORS issue. but when i remove it no CORS

Comment: You need to enable CORS on server side

Comment: fix should be like this in FE request but also in server should be set up